# Ajax Request Not Posting Data on Server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

.htaccess Code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
#for normal domains like example.com or example.in to redirect to https://www.example.com
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.(com|in|org)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

ErrorDocument 404 /errorPages/404.php

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+details\.php\?event=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ details/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^details/([^/]+)/?$ details.php?events=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# We are setting here the default file to load while the URL is called followed by fallback files
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Redirect all requests except only POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:php?)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

This is my JQuery-Ajax Code:

```
var form = new FormData($('#regForm')[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: "/register",
    type: "POST",
    data: form,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data)
      {
        if(data == "ack")
          {
            $("form#regForm")[0].reset();
            $("#message1").slideDown("slow");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#message1").slideUp("slow");
              }, 5000);
          }

        else if(data == "nak")
          {
            $('#regForm').find('input, button, select').removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#register").text("Register Now!");
            $("#message2").slideDown("slow");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#message2").slideUp("slow");
              }, 5000);
          }

        else
          {
            console.log(data);
          }
      },
    error:function(data){}
});
```

This is the PHP Code:

```
<?php
      print_r($_POST);
      exit();
?>
```

This is the HTML Code:

```
<form id="regForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="event">Event / Workshop?</label>
  <select id="vid_event" name="vid_event" class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected value="">Select Event..</option>
    <option value="Crack-A-Thon">(Workshop)</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="addSubevent">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Your Full Name</label>
  <input onkeypress="return IsChar(event);" type="name" class="form-control" name="vid_name" id="vid_name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="mobile">Your Mobile Number</label>
  <input minlength="10" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" type="text" class="form-control" name="vid_mobile" id="vid_mobile">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="college">Your College Name</label>
  <input onkeypress="return IsChar(event);" type="text" class="form-control" name="vid_college" id="vid_college">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="course">Course Field?</label>
  <select id="vid_course" name="vid_course" class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected value="">Select Course..</option>
    <option value="11th">11th</option>
    <option value="12th">12th</option>
    <option value="Diploma">Diploma / Poly</option>
    <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
    <option value="Post Graduation">Post Graduation</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="vid_year">Which Year?</span></label>
  <select id="vid_year" name="vid_year" class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected value="">Select Year..</option>
    <option value="First">First Year</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="register" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Register Now!</button>
</form>
```

When i am printing the data on PHP server it shows a blank array and no data is being posted! Why So? What is wrong with the code logic?

Everytime, i post the data to server it shows a blank array always i thought that there is code error but it not like that as its not giving any error.

Comment: Probably your variable `form` in JavaScript is not getting populated. Debug its value

Comment: Try to send form data using Serialize.

Comment: Shouldn't the URL at least contain the file extension of the file you are submitting to?

Comment: @SPlatten - it could be aliased as such with `.htaccess` rewrite rule

Comment: @RamRaider, but is it?

Comment: @SPlatten i have set the .htaccess rules so it properly posts the data there

Comment: In your form you haven't specified a method, set the attribute method="POST"

Comment: @SPlatten does it really affect as i am using ajax and i have set there the post method

Comment: print variable 'form' before sending ajax request or see your network console to know if data is sent as post

Comment: @SPlatten: setting form method to post is not required as its an ajax call here.

Comment: how is the javascript code triggered? I dont see a `click` event handler

Comment: AJAX has nothing to do with it, the webserver gets a request, the server variables are populated according to if the request is using the GET or POST method.  Try looking at the HTTP_Server variable to see if that helps.

Comment: There is no function that is calling to execute the Ajax code! Write a function with Ajax code inside of it and trigger the function when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: @HariHarker i have done the click function is it due to .htaccess

Comment: try this var form = $('form')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);